# How can i save RDD to a single parquet file?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I work with pyspark 2.0, hadoop 2.7.2.
And here is my code:

```
def func(df):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['id'])
    new_df['num'] = new_df['num'] * 12
    return new_df

set = sqlContext.read.parquet("data_set.parquet")
columns = set.columns
map_res = set.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iter_: func(pd.DataFrame(list(iter_), 
                                                   columns=columns)))
```

Now, I need to save **map_res** RDD as a parquet file *new.parquet*. 
Is there any way i can do it without creating a large dataframe before the saving? Or may be there is a possibility of saving each partition of RDD separately and then merge all saved files?

P.s. I want to manage without creating a dataframe due to its realy large size.

Comment: @santon It seems it is required to merge all single dataframes into large one preserving the schema. Keeping them as elements of  RDD won't allow to manipulate with results as with DataFrame.

Comment: @ИванСудос correct, so i don't want all the data to be moved to one node

Comment: @santon when you make pipelines single parquet-files as parameters are easier to deal with

Answer (score 2):

There are only 2 ways to do this:

One is use `"coalesce(1)"`
This will make sure that all the data is saved into 1 file rather than multiple files (200 is the spark default no of partitions) use `dataframe.write.save("/this/is/path")`.

The other option is write the output to a hive table and then use `hive -e "select * from table" > data.tsv` which will be tab separated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this:

```
dataframes = []
#creating index
map_res = map_res.zipWithIndex()
# setting index as key
map_res = map_res.map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
# creating one spark df per element
for i in range(0, map_res.count()):
    partial_dataframe_pd  = map_res.lookup(i)
    partial_dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(partial_dataframe_pd)
    dataframes.append(partial_dataframe)
# concatination
result_df = dataframes.pop()
for df in dataframes:
    result_df.union(df)   
#saving
result_df.write.parquet("...")
```

If you have small number of partitions (2-100) then it should work rather fast.

Answer (score 0):

To save a file in Parquet format , you need to convert Rdd to DataFrame, As Parquet File always need a schema for processing .

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
set.coalesce(1).write.parquet("myFile.parquet")
```